# Can not unmount SDA partition in GParted

Tags: boot, 13.04, gparted, unmount

My /boot partition got full with updates, so I wanted to make it larger.

I booted from a live disk, but my main partition is not unmountable (and thus not resizeable, so I can't make it smaller to make the boot bigger.)

Comment: we need more information. What error do you get when you unmount your partition(s)? Sometimes it is easier to use the gparted live CD.

Comment: If you boot from a live disk, isn't that your SDA? Did you check the drive to make sure you are really selecting your HD?

Answer (score 1):

While you do need to give more information, one possible reason is that another partition is mounted under the partition you are trying to *umount*.

First off, run the following commands and add them to your post:

```
$ df -a -h -T
$ mount  (No options)
```

One example of what I mean would be if you using EFI boot and you have a GPT disk.  In that case, when you are booted normally, you have partitions mounted below other partitions, as follows:

```
/
/boot
/boot/efi
```

In this case, you wouldn't be able to unmount **/boot**, until you unmounted **/boot/efi**.

So, check the output of the *df* command above (and post it), too see what other mounts might be preventing you from unmounting /boot.